# VS Code code formatting for TypeScript and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm looking for extensions or JSON settings to format my code given below:

```
if(true)
{
}
else
{
}
```

and not like below:

```
if(true){
} else {
}
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer modified the json setting:

```
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
"typescript.format.enable": true,
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true, 
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,

"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add these lines in your settings.json.

```
{
  "[javascript][typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
}
```